# How to check if a character from a list is in a given set?

Tags: python, string, set

Given a set of valid chars in Python:

```
valid_chars = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "-", "."}
```

I'm trying to find out if two strings are only formed by characters in the set, and if not, the method will return False.

```
for char in zip(latitude, longitude):
    if char not in valid_chars:
        return False
```

At first glance, I'd say this piece of code should work fine, but no matter which strings I input the method will always return False. Is there something I'm missing here?

EDIT: Gonna provide some more information about what I'm trying to do: The method should check if a string of coordinates is valid or not by checking if there are not invalid characters in the latitude and the longitude.

Here's an example of what the method should receive:

```
is_valid_coordinates("24.53525235, 23.45235") => True
is_valid_coordinates("0.342q0832, 1.2324") => False
```

And this is how I get the latitude and longitude from the given parameter:

```
latitude = coordinates[:coordinates.index(',')]
longitude = coordinates[coordinates.index(',') + 2:]
```

Comment: For any string that you want to check: `all(c in valid_chars for c in my_str)`

Comment: Perhaps you meant to combine the strings `latitude + longitude` instead of `zip(latitude, longitude)`?

Comment: Yeah, zip method was a mistake, that wasn't meant to work. Anyways, even that way I keep getting the same results.

Comment: @McNeto We don't know what those iterables/lists contain. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why don't you show us an example where it goes wrong?

Comment: I assume latitude and longitude are strings. If that's the case, then you should note that `valid_chars` isn't a set of chars, but a set of 10 integers and 2 strings/chars. It should probably be a list of 12 strings/chars instead.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I edited the question and added some more information now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` returns a tuple, but your set contains no tuple of characters, so there is no chance this will work.

OTOH, you can check if *all* the items in each tuple are contained using the builtin `all`:

```
...
for chr1, chr2 in zip(latitude, longitude):
    if chr1 not in valid_chars or chr2 not in valid_chars:
        return False
```

However, I'm not sure why you need to `zip` in the first place. If you need need to iterate through all the items in both iterables, you can use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

for char in chain(latitude, longitude):
    if char not in valid_chars:
        return False
```

**Update**

You can *try* to parse the values as floats and see if that works:

```
...
try:
   lat, lon = "24.53525235, 23.45235".split(",")
   float(lat), float(lon)
except ValueError:
   return False
else:
   return True
```

Comment: That's totally true, my bad. Anyway, even without the zip method and writing the loop like this:
    for char in latitude, longitude:
I keep getting the same problem

Comment: Not sure what you're hoping to get with that. You want to iterate on all the items in both iterables?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
all(set(word) <= valid_chars for word in [longitude, latitude])
```

`set(word)` maps the string to the set of its characters and `<=` is the subset condition.

Note: You should convert the numbers in `valid_chars` to strings, i.e. `"1"` instead of `1` to make this work properly.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `zip` with two variables;

`for char1,char2 in zip(latitude, longitude):`

this way the elements of latitude will match with the elements in longitude by their indexes. So every `char1` match with `char2`.

Then check them if they are in that specific list;

```
if char1 not in valid_chars or char2 not in valid_chars:
    return false
```

if `char1` or `char2` not in `valid_chars`, this will return false.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers point out, every item in the result of your `zip` is a pair.

Insead, concatenate the lists to get desired behavior:

```
for char in longitude + latitude:
    if char not in valid_chars:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to provide chars in the valid_chars :

```
valid_chars = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', "-", "."}
```

Then the code for your method could be as in this:

```
def isvalid_coordinates(str):
    valid_chars = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', "-", "."}
    coords=str.split(", ")
    cooncatenation=coords[0]+coords[1]
    for char in cooncatenation:
        if char not in valid_chars:
            return False;
    return True;
def main():
    print isvalid_coordinates("24.53525235, 23.45235")
    print isvalid_coordinates("0.342q0832, 1.2324")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```